# Monty Hall simulator is not working properly

Tags: python

I tried to simulate Monty Hall problem.

First I choosed the winning door and randomized a selection. Then opened a door which is not the selected door. Then checked if selected = winning door. If it is, I added 1 to not switching point (b.num).

Then to switch the selection, I removed selected door from the doors list and equalized selected to the only item in the list. Then checked if selected = winning door again and if it is I added 1 to switching point (s.num1).

The problem is switching win percent is roughly equal 33. The expected value of it is about 66. Where is the problem?

```
import random
from random import randint

def b():
    b.num+=1
b.num=0

def s():
    s.num+=1
s.num=0

d=int(input("try count: "))

def a():
    winner=randint(1,3)
    selection=randint(1,3)
    doors=[1,2,3]
    doors_to_open=randint(1,2)
    if selection == 1:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(2)
        else:
            doors.remove(3)

    if selection == 2:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(1)
        else:
            doors.remove(3)

    if selection == 3:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(1)
        else:
            doors.remove(2)

    if selection == winner:
        b()
        #print("Not switching win count: ",b.num)

    # switch

    doors.remove(selection)
    selection = doors[0]

    if selection == winner:
        s()
        #print("Switching win count: ",s.num)

for q in range (0,d):
    a()

#print("Switching win count: ",s.num)
print("Switching percent: ",(s.num/d)*100)
#print("Not switching win count: ",b.num)
print("Not switching percent: ",(b.num/d)*100)

input()
```

Comment: It looks like you are opening doors without consulting whether they are winners or not. Monty never opens a winning door.

Comment: yeah I think you are right thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(thanks to Mark Meyer) the problem has solved. That code was opening the winning door too. Here is the proper code:

```
import random
from random import randint

def a():
    a.sayı+=1
a.sayı=0

def b():
    b.sayı+=1
b.sayı=0

def c():
    kapılar=[1,2,3]
    cevap=randint(1,3)
    seçim=randint(1,3)

    #kapı aç
    kapılar1=[1,2,3]
    if seçim==cevap:
        kapılar1.remove(cevap)
    else:
            kapılar1.remove(cevap)
            kapılar1.remove(seçim)
    #kapılar1.remove(cevap)
    #kapılar1.remove(seçim)
    kapılar.remove(kapılar1[0])

    #dont switch
    if seçim==cevap:
        a()

    #switch
    kapılar.remove(seçim)
    seçim=kapılar[0]

    if seçim==cevap:
        b()

d=int(input("Deneme sayısı: "))

for e in range(0,d):
    c()

print("Switching win percent: ",(b.sayı/d)*100)
print("Not switching win pecent: ",(a.sayı/d)*100)
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed a not equal to operator while calling s function. if you add ! in the condition. it will fix your simulation.

```
import random
from random import randint

def b():
    b.num+=1
b.num=0

def s():
    s.num+=1
s.num=0

d=int(input("try count: "))

def a():
    winner=randint(1,3)
    selection=randint(1,3)
    doors=[1,2,3]
    doors_to_open=randint(1,2)
    if selection == 1:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(2)
        else:
            doors.remove(3)

    if selection == 2:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(1)
        else:
            doors.remove(3)

    if selection == 3:
        if doors_to_open==1:
            doors.remove(1)
        else:
            doors.remove(2)

    if selection == winner:
        b()
        #print("Not switching win count: ",b.num)

    # switch

    doors.remove(selection)
    selection = doors[0]

    if selection != winner: #Change is done in this line
        s()
        #print("Switching win count: ",s.num)

for q in range (0,d):
    a()

#print("Switching win count: ",s.num)
print("Switching percent: ",(s.num/d)*100)
#print("Not switching win count: ",b.num)
print("Not switching percent: ",(b.num/d)*100)
```